# Unable to Access Mutation Record values

Tags: javascript, mutation-observers

Within the `MutationObserver(function(mutations){...`

I've printed this using this line:

```
console.log('0=', mutations[0]);
```

How do I access this value:

```
id:"lbltime"
```

It does not work when I use  `mutations[0].id` or

```
mutations[0].target.id
```

---

Here is the snippet of the relevant code:

```
 gg_observer = new MutationObserver(function (mutations)
                {

                    if (mutations.length == 1)
                        {
                            console.log('mmm=', mutations[0].target);
                            console.log('id=', mutations[0].id);
                            console.log('0=', mutations[0]);
                        }
                    console.log("mutations =", mutations);
                    mutations.forEach(function (mutation)
                        {
                            console.log("mutation=", mutation);
                        });
//function continues below which I've removed
```

[image]

Comment: Ah, some sites assign `id` to elements later so it might be absent in the callback but shown in the console as it's rendered lazily afterwards.

Comment: @wOxxOm I've given